# Sort a flat array in recurring ascending sequences

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, sequential

I am trying to sort it in a repeating, sequential pattern of numerical order with the largest sets first.

Sample array:

```
$array = [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,4,4,5,1,2,2,3];
```

In the above array, I have the highest value of 5 which appears twice so the first two sets would `1,2,3,4,5` then it would revert to the second, highest value set etc.

Desired result:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,4]
```

I am pretty sure I can split the array into chunks of the integer values then cherrypick an item from each subarray sequentially until there are no remaining items, but I just feel that this is going to be poor for performance and I don't want to miss a simple trick that PHP can already handle.

Comment: Well, despite researching it for the last hour or so using different search terms I can't find a standard PHP function that handles this kind of sort to even start basing my logic from. I am pretty sure I can split the array into chunks of the integer values then cherrypick an item from each subarray sequentially until there are no remaining items but I just feel that this is going to be poor for performance and I don't want to miss a simple trick that PHP can already handle.

Comment: I get frustrated that there are (what appear to be) 100's of array functions, but to expect one to fit every need is a bit much.  BUT showing your own effort will more likely get others to contribute and not feel as though they are just doing your work for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how sucesfull you might be with a custom [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) but if you wanted a manual approach I'd be sorting them into a sub arrays index by the number, then iterating over the outer set picking from the inner set untill each inner set is exhausted.

Comment: @NigelRen a pointer in the right direction is all I need. I can write my own code if I have that point but I can't seem to find what I need in the document sets I have read.

Comment: @Scuzzy, yeah, that is the backup plan I have but for performance, I was hoping PHP would have something already existing to handle this seemingly simple sequential pattern.

Comment: `array_count_values($array)` may be a start, but it does say there are 4 4's, yet the result only shows 3.

Comment: @NigelRen that doesn't give a starting point for my issue but it is a part of my backup plan. Your responses seem quite defensive. I am not after somebody to write my code for me. As stated in my original post I was merely asking for a pointer in the right direction to any functions that I may be missing after I did my own research which I believe is the correct usage of the Stack Overflow platform.

Comment: Not sure where you get defensive from, but there are a lot of questions that get downvoted and closed as the poster refuses to show their efforts.  I am merely asking to see what you have done so far and perhaps then offer some advice on how to improve/fix it.  I've also asked for clarification as to why there are more 4's in the input than the output.

Comment: @NigelRen it just came off that way to be honest. I clearly defined I was simply after a pointer is all. I get that you have probably helped hundreds who do not do their own research first but I am not that guy. The researching I have done hasn't allowed me to find a decent starting point to begin constructing my solution Thank you for your help, it is appreciated and I apologise if I have the wrong end of the stick. it just seemed defensive. The missing 4 is a typo. Updated.

Comment: I suspect the reason you're struggling to find neat solutions to this is that it's not actually a very common problem. It's going to be more a case of designing an elegant algorithm than finding an off-the-shelf solution, or anything particularly PHP specific.

Comment: @IMSoP yeah, I think you are right. You know when you are building something though and you just keep thinking that there must be a better way? Yeah, that lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only linear logic to sort using php functions. Here is optimized way to fill data structures. It can be used for streams, generators or anything else you can iterate and compare.

```
$array = array(1,1,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,4,4,5,1,2,2,3);
sort($array);
$chunks = [];
$index = [];
foreach($array as $i){
    if(!isset($index[$i])){
        $index[$i]=0;
    }
    if(!isset($chunks[$index[$i]])){
        $chunks[$index[$i]]=[$i];
    } else {
        $chunks[$index[$i]][] = $i;
    }
    $index[$i]++;
}
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $chunks);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This actually works really well. I had chunking or `chanking` :D as my backup option but didn't want to miss out on a simple function that may have handled this for me. I think most of the responses are going to be based around this method so I will start using this as my basis for the remainder of my function. Thank you.

Comment: i think this can be optimized by sorting input array and indexing chunks ( or `chanks` :D ), i`ll update my answer.

Comment: A definite performance gain will be using `array_key_exists` rather than `in_array`.

Comment: @IMSoP indexing should be faster, cause we can avoid inner loop and in_array check and sort loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at a very manual loop using process, the idea is to simply sort the numbers into containers for array_unshifting. I'm sure this is terrible and I'd love someone to do this in five lines or less :)

```
$array = array(1,1,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,4,4,5,1,2,2,3);
sort($array);
// Build the container array
$numbers = array_fill_keys(array_unique($array),array());
// Assignment
foreach( $array as $number )
{
  $numbers[ $number ][] = $number;
}

// Worker Loop
$output = array();
while( empty( $numbers ) === false )
{
  foreach( $numbers as $outer => $inner )
  {
    $output[] = array_shift( $numbers[ $outer ] );
    if( empty( $numbers[ $outer ] ) )
    {
      unset( $numbers[ $outer ] );
    }
  }
}

var_dump( $output );
```

Comment: This is very similar to my approach, but without the shortcut of counting the values in each set rather than listing them. I would probably skip the array_fill_keys step and just create entries as needed, which saves a lot of pre-processing (sort, unique, etc) on the full array.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd look at this not as a sorting problem, but alternating values from multiple lists, so rather than coming up with sets of distinct numbers I'd make sets of *the same* number.

Since there's no difference between one 1 and another, all you actually need is to count the number of times each appears. It turns out PHP can do this for you with [aaray_count_values](http://php.net/array_count_values).

```
$sets = array_count_values ($input);
```

Then we can make sure the sets are in order by sorting by key:

```
ksort($sets);
```

Now, we iterate round our sets, counting down how many times we've output each number. Once we've "drained" a set, we remove it from the list, and once we have no sets left, we're all done:

```
$output = [];
while ( count($sets) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $sets as $number => $count ) {
        $output[] = $number;
        if ( --$sets[$number] == 0 ) {
            unset($sets[$number]);
        }
     }
 }
```

This algorithm could be adapted for cases where the values are actually distinct but can be put into sets, by having the value of each set be a list rather than a count. Instead of -- you'd use array_shift, and then check if the length of the set was zero.

Comment: this is a nice solution. Thank you. I suppose I was getting bogged down by the notion that this had to be a sort I missed out a logical path that is streamlined.

Comment: Nice point of view. Counting can be used as full index and no need to chunk data.

Comment: As for "sets" variant i`d prefer my solution, less loops, actual result set on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array(1,1,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,4,4,5,1,2,2,3);
sort($array);

while($array) {
    $n = 0;
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if($v>$n) {
            $result[] = $n = $v;
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
}

echo implode(',', $result);
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,4
```

Answer (score 0):

New, more elegant, more performant, more concise answer:

Create a sorting array where each number gets its own independent counter to increment.  Then use `array_multisort()` to sort by this grouping array, then sort by values ascending.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NWiEL))

```
$encounters = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $encounters[] = $e[$v] = ($e[$v] ?? 0) + 1;
}

array_multisort($encounters, $array);
var_export($array);
```

Or with a functional style with no global variable declarations: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7HDm2))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(
        function($v) {
            static $e;
            return $e[$v] = ($e[$v] ?? 0) + 1;
        },
        $array
    ),
    $array
);
var_export($array);
```

---

Old answer:

My advice is functionally identical to @El''s snippet, but is implemented in a more concise/modern/attractive fashion.

After ensuring that the input array is sorted, make only one pass over the array and push each re-encountered value into its next row of values.  The `$counter` variable indicates which row (in `$grouped`) the current value should be pushed into.  When finished looping and grouping, `$grouped` will have unique values in each row.  The final step is to merge/flatten the rows (preserving their order).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hKvmQ))

```
$grouped = [];
$counter = [];
sort($array);
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $counter[$v] = ($counter[$v] ?? -1) + 1;
    $grouped[$counter[$v]][] = $v;
}
var_export(array_merge(...$grouped));
```