# Make sure the same array items are not next to each other in php

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I am struggling with this case. I have a random array that similar items can be in the next to each other and I don't want it to happen.

Example :

```
array("red","red","blue","green","green","blue");

Expected Output : array("red","blue","red","green","blue","green")
```

So I was thinking about shuffle the items until there are no similar items in the next to each other. But it will take a lot of time if the array has a lot of values.

Is there any effective way to make it happen?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: the purpose is no consecutive element will not be the same right? event if red goes at the (near) end and blue is first it is not a problem ?

Comment: yes, that's enough for me

Comment: Topical Javascript page: [How to avoid consecutive selection of the same element when shuffling two arrays in the same order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65543095/2943403)  Different yet somewhat related PHP pages: [Get n number of random values from an array and prevent consecutively repeated values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74273534/2943403) and [Sort a flat array in recurring ascending sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51114257/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea:

- Shuffle the original array.
- Compare the first two. If they are the same, swap second with the last.
- Move to the next pair.
- Repeat until end reached.

Here we assume the worst case shuffle having the same values next together.

```php
$colors = ["red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green", "green"];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($colors) - 1; $i++) {
    if ($colors[$i] !== $colors[$i + 1]) continue;
    $last = $colors[count($colors) - 1];
    $colors[count($colors) - 1] = $colors[$i];
    $colors[$i + 1] = $last;
}

print_r($colors);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => green
    [2] => blue
    [3] => red
    [4] => green
    [5] => blue
)
```

Comment: This idea will work only if the similar item has the same count. And it won't work if the array has value like this `$colors = ["red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "green", "green", "blue"];`. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: and the hardest part is my data can be like this `["red","red","red","red","red","red","blue","blue","green","green","green","green","green","green","red","red","red"]`

Comment: Sure, the less unique words, the worse this will work. But if the array is large enough you  wont' have same results next together. You could run the routine and check count the swaps. And run again until no swaps are done or swap count is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-arrange to a new array. For those who have the same problem with me here is how I do it :

```
<?php

$colors = ["red","red","red","red","red","red","blue","blue","green","green","green","green","green","green","red","red","red"];
$newColors = array();

$uniqColors = array_values(array_unique($colors));

$countUniqColors = count($uniqColors);

$y = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($colors) - 1; $i++) {
    $newColors[$i] = $uniqColors[$y];
    $y += 1;
    if ($y >= $countUniqColors) $y = 0; 
}

print_r($newColors);

?>
```

I think this is the most effective way I can think of. Let me know if you have any thought about this solution

Answer (score 0):

Just another idea:

- Take the array and scan from start to end
- Compare the next with current, when not equal, then continue
- Compare the next with current, when equal, search the next different and swap next with next different

Based on your comment of an even more worse case than in the original question, I suggest trying this, ensuring never one word will be twice next together.

```php
$colors = ["red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "red", "red", "red"];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($colors) - 1; $i++) {
    if ($colors[$i] !== $colors[$i + 1]) continue;

    for ($k = $i + 2; $k < count($colors) - 1; $k++) {
        if ($colors[$i + 1] === $colors[$k]) continue;
        $tmp = $colors[$i + 1];
        $colors[$i + 1] = $colors[$k];
        $colors[$k] = $tmp;
        break;
    }
}

print_r($colors);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
    [2] => red
    [3] => blue
    [4] => red
    [5] => green
    [6] => red
    [7] => green
    [8] => red
    [9] => green
    [10] => red
    [11] => green
    [12] => red
    [13] => green
    [14] => red
    [15] => green
    [16] => red
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force/stupid solution would be:

1. shuffle array
2. iterate through and check if neighbours are equal
3. if yes, increment $i
4. use do{} while($i != 0)

Like so:

```
<?php
    
$colors = ["red","red","red","red","red","red","blue","blue","green","green","green","green","green","green","red","red","red"];
    
do{
    shuffle($colors);
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($colors as $value) {

        if(isset($oldValue)){
            if($oldValue == $value){
                $i++;
            }
        }

        $oldValue = $value;
    }

} while ($i != 0);

?>
```

Of course, the more duplicities you possibly have, the more demanding the script will be. But it works fine for smaller arrays.