# How to avoid consecutive selection of the same element when shuffling two arrays in the same order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I have two arrays (below) and I have to shuffle the two lists in the same order. Actually, when I research other Q/A topics, I partially figure out how to get around this problem. But I need one more thing: Suppose you have the same items in an array (list1). And once an item is selected, at least 2 other items must be selected before the item can be re-selected. How can it be done?

Also, list1 and list2 must be shuffled in the same order.

I would appreciate your help.

Current arrays:

```
List1 = ["imgA", "imgA", "imgA","imgB", "imgB", "imgB","imgC", "imgC", "imgC","imgD", "imgD", "imgD"];

List2 = ["durationA", "durationA", "durationA","durationB", "durationB", "durationB","durationC", "durationC", "durationC","durationD", "durationD", "durationD"];
```

Example of expected arrays:

```
List1 = ["imgB", "imgC", "imgA","imgB", "imgD", "imgA","imgC", "imgD", "imgA","imgC", "imgD", "imgB"];

List2 = ["durationB", "durationC", "durationA","durationB", "durationD", "durationA","durationC", "durationD", "durationA","durationC", "durationD", "durationB"]
```

Comment: So at this point you're just asking how to prevent selection of an item in an array until at least two other items have been selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an array of the last two items selected and then checking if that array `includes` the item you just selected.

```js
const lastTwo = [null, null];

function getItem(item) {
  if (lastTwo.includes(item)) {
    console.log("Can't select this item yet!");
    return;
  }
  lastTwo.push(item);
  lastTwo.shift();
  console.log(`You selected ${item}`);
}

getItem(1);
getItem(2);
getItem(1); // Not allowed yet
getItem(3);
getItem(1); // Now it's allowed
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your help:) Actually i am struggling to solve both shuffling two lists simultaneously and prevent consecutive selection of two items I'm very new to coding so I don't know how to use your suggestion for my purpose. However, I will try. Thanks again.