# How to sort an array by uniqueness in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting

I have a list of arrays with values ​​inside each array. I want to sort my list based on one of these values ​​so that unique arrays are displayed first, then duplicate arrays.
I don't want any member to be removed from the array, I just want my array to be sorted

this is the list that I have

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 35
    "answer" => null
    "type" => 3
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 36
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 36
    "answer" => null
    "type" => 3
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 36
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]
  2 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 37
    "answer" => "Gello"
    "type" => 0
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 37
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]
  3 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 38
    "answer" => "Uho"
    "type" => 0
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 37
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]
  4 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 39
    "answer" => "Who"
    "type" => 1
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 38
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]
  5 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 40
    "answer" => "Window"
    "type" => 1
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 38
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:40.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:40.000000Z"
  ]
]
```

and I want to sort by `question_id`. I want my list to eventually become this list

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 35
    "answer" => null
    "type" => 3
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 36
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]
  2 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 37
    "answer" => "Hello"
    "type" => 0
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 37
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]
  4 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 39
    "answer" => "Who"
    "type" => 1
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 38
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 36
    "answer" => null
    "type" => 3
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 36
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]
  3 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 38
    "answer" => "Uho"
    "type" => 0
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 37
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:39.000000Z"
  ]

  5 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 40
    "answer" => "Window"
    "type" => 1
    "user_id" => 9
    "question_id" => 38
    "answer_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:40.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-04-07T09:03:40.000000Z"
  ]
]
```

Comment: as you use Laravel, you can just create a `collection` of that array and use the [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-groupby) function in combination with [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-unique) but i doubt you need unique values.

Comment: Hi dear friend. I don't want the members of my array to be destroyed by the unique function, nor do I want a new array to be created in my list. I want to be able to sort by unique function. It means that non-matching members should be displayed first. After that, the members that are similar to the first members will be displayed

Comment: @AmiraliPourmoshir Always `var_export` your array while showing input data and output data here on SO. Also, what are your attempts for this?

Comment: @AmiraliPourmoshir a [demo of my advice from the dupe target](https://3v4l.org/eZ8BD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would actually need to use a map/set to store rows per each question ID. Then use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to make them appear group by group.

**Note:** Since yours is a Laravel collections, you can simply use `->toArray()` to convert it to a PHP array and use the code below!

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$set = [];
$result = [];
$maxColumns = 0;

foreach($records as $r){
   $set[ $r['question_id'] ] = $set[ $r['question_id'] ] ?? [];
   $set[ $r['question_id'] ][] = $r;
   $maxColumns = max($maxColumns, count($set[ $r['question_id'] ]));
}

for($i = 0; $i < $maxColumns; ++$i){
    $result = array_merge($result, array_column($set, $i));
}

print_r($result);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/F7dE5)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807468/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like returned data from DB, it depends on that what you use:

- DB class -> https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#ordering
  `DB::table('table_name')->orderBy('question_id')->get()->toArray();`
- Eloquent -> https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-models
  `Model::orderBy('question_id)->get()->toArray();`

Comment: Hi dear friend. The answer you gave has no effect on the performance of this array. Because the array is already sorted by question_id

Answer (score 0):

as you mention you are having an array this can be a proper solution for it

```
<?php 
$records =[
  [
    "id" => 1,
    "user_id" => 9,
    "question_id" => 16,
    "answer_id" => 1,
  ],
  [
    "id" => 2,
    "user_id" => 9,
    "question_id" => 26,
    "answer_id" => 1,
  ],
  [
    "id" => 3,
    "user_id" => 9,
    "question_id" => 6,
    "answer_id" => 1,
  ],
  [
    "id" => 13,
    "user_id" => 9,
    "question_id" => 36,
    "answer_id" => 1,
  ],
  [
    "id" => 18,
    "user_id" => 9,
    "question_id" => 26,
    "answer_id" => 1,
  ],
    [
    "id" => 21,
    "user_id" => 9,
    "question_id" => 06,
    "answer_id" => 1,
  ],
  [
    "id" => 21,
    "user_id" => 9,
    "question_id" => 11,
    "answer_id" => 1,
  ],
];

function sortCallback($firstRecord,$secondRecord){
    return $firstRecord['question_id']>$secondRecord['question_id'] ;
}
$recordsCopy=$records;
usort($recordsCopy,"sortCallback");
print_r($recordsCopy);

?>
```

but it is a Larvel collection then you can sort method of it with same call back method.

Comment: You can't use boolean result as a way of sorting comparison in your callback. It needs integer values to be returned!