# Sort a 2D array by column value into recurring ascending groups of not more than N of a kind

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting, array-column

I have an array that contains other associative arrays as its values. Each one of these "sub" arrays is mapped with key-value pairs:

```php
$items = [
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'A'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'B'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'C'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'D'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'E'],
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'F'],
    ['type' => 4, 'text' => 'G'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'H'],
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'I'],
    ['type' => 4, 'text' => 'J'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'K'],
    ['type' => 4, 'text' => 'L'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'M'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'N'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'O'],
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'P'],
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'Q'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'R'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'S'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'T'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'U'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'V'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'W'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'X'],
    ['type' => 4, 'text' => 'Y'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'Z'],
];
```

How can I sort this array and return as another array, with the following requirements?

1. It needs to sort the associative arrays by its `type`.
2. It needs to do this by picking the first 3 items that show up in the `$items` array, and then moving on to the next type, which is `2`, and doing the same. The max amount of `types` there are in my code is `8`, but theoretically it should work with any number.
3. If it has picked out 3 of each type one time, restart again with the remainder of items in the array, starting at type `1` again.

Essentially you should get another array which -- from top to bottom -- has values with their types in alternated orders, something like this:

```
[
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'A'],
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'F'],
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'I'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'B'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'C'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'E'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'D'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'N'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'O'],
    ['type' => 4, 'text' => 'G'],
    ['type' => 4, 'text' => 'J'],
    ['type' => 4, 'text' => 'L'],
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'P'],
    ['type' => 1, 'text' => 'Q'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'H'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'K'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'M'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'S'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'U'],
    ['type' => 3, 'text' => 'W'],
    ['type' => 4, 'text' => 'Y'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'R'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'T'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'V'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'X'],
    ['type' => 2, 'text' => 'Z'],
]
```

The `text` does not matter to the sorting.

I've actually gone as far as to make a YouTube video to better explain what should happen: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCz1OTsuSxU)

My current thought process was to use a separate array called `$groups`, use a `foreach` loop eight different times, and in each one, continue the loop if it's not for the specific type. For example:

```php
// My above $items array example here

// Initialize $groups
$groups = [];

// foreach for type 1
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // If any of the items are not of type 1, ignore and continue
    if ($item["type"] !== 1) {
        continue;
    }
    // Otherwise, push to $groups
    array_push($groups, $item["type"];
}

// foreach for type 2
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // If any of the items are not of type 2, ignore and continue
    if ($item["type"] !== 2) {
        continue;
    }
    // Otherwise, push to $groups
    array_push($groups, $item["type"];
}

// Do this for each possible type, up to type 8
```

This not only does this seem extremely inefficient and backwards, I just feel there is a better way to go about it or another angle I'm missing. I don't believe the above code is even close to the solution.

Comment: Regardless, I've edited the original question to be more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think setting up `array_multisort()` to do this job makes logical sense (since this is a sorting task).
Note that my demonstration will sort the actual input array (make yourself a copy if you need to preserve the original).

1. Iterate the input array.
2. Populate a flat mapping array with increasing grouping ids.
3. Populate a flat mapping array of type values.
4. Call `array_multisort()` to sort on `$grouper`, then `$column`, then `$items` (then you can access `$items`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EGY6b)) ([Alt Demo](https://3v4l.org/cOSO1))

```
$maxConsecutive = 3;

$grouper = [];
$column = [];
foreach ($items as $row) {
    $column[] = $row['type'];  // preserve isolated type values
    $encountered[$row['type']] ??= 0; // declare the default value of 0 for the first encounter of a given type value
    $grouper[] = intdiv($encountered[$row['type']]++, $maxConsecutive); // access the cached counter for the given type, divide it by 3, omit any decimal values; then increment the counter (post-incrementation `++` only increases the value AFTER it is used)
}

array_multisort($grouper, $column, $items); // sort by grouper ASC, column ASC, then items ASC
var_export($items);
```

<sub>Somewhat related is [Sort a flat array in recurring ascending sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51114257/2943403) which has a hardcoded grouping N of 1 (instead of 3) while sorting data in ascending recurring sequences.</sub>

---

Alternatively, you can group the data into subsets, then sort, then consume the grouped data while populating the new result.
Though, I will state that this doesn't feel as professional as the `array_multisort()` approach for a sorting task.

1. Group the rows by their `type` value.
2. Sort by the new first level keys.
3. Use a self-extending `foreach()` loop (notice the `&` in the signature) to push only the first N rows per group into the result array. If the current group still has elements, push the whole group onto the end of the array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Epa7C))

```
$maxConsecutive = 3;

$grouped = [];
foreach ($items as $row) {
    $grouped[$row['type']][] = $row;
}

ksort($grouped);

$result = [];
foreach ($grouped as &$group) {
    array_push($result, ...array_splice($group, 0, $maxConsecutive));
    if ($group) {
        $grouped[] = $group;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

As a microoptimization, you can extract the entire payload of the last remaining group with: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rFW55))

```
array_push($result, ...array_splice($group, 0, count($grouped) === 1 ? null : $maxConsecutive));
```

Comment: The first version of your code here I personally like best (for my use case) because it's short and sweet and prevents me from having to push data to a different array, it simply sorts the array itself. Basically, from what it seems to me, it changes the order of the `$items` array itself correct? Intact, but in the desired order? I made a test case, and it worked flawlessly. Sorry to @nigel but this seems to be a better answer--cleaner code, shorter, more precise. One thing I do ask--would it be possible to add comments to document exactly what is going on here to make it easier to pick up?

Comment: Yes, `array_multisort()` will mutate the original array without needing to declare a new copy of the array. I added inline comments to my snippet.  It may be helpful for you to `var_export($column)`, `var_export($encountered)`, and `var_export($grouper)` to see what values they hold.

Comment: The array_multisort is exactly how I would have answered this.

Comment: Yes, I've done a little bit of digging into it (at least the first snippet) to break down exactly what's going on and honestly it seems like a perfect solution. It was extremely easy to re-write to fit into my application as well for what I actually need it for. (My actual code is not 100% the same; I just needed the concept). Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this demo](https://3v4l.org/l0kr2) will clarify how the generated arrays are used to sort the rows.

Answer (score 2):

This first creates a count of each type, then loops till there is nothing output. The inner loop will output the number of items you want (as long as that type has something left to output) adjusting the remaining left as you go along.

I've commented the code which should explain it clearer.

```
// Create text lookup array, indexed by type
$types = array_column($items, null, 'type');
// Count the number of each type there are
$breakdown = array_count_values(array_column($items, 'type'));

// Sort by the key to create desired order
ksort($breakdown);

$breakSize = 3;

do {
    // If flag doesn't change then nothing is left to output
    $anyOutput = false;
    foreach ($breakdown as $key => &$countLeft) {
        // Loop while less than the break size but also with something left
        for ($i = 0; $i < $breakSize && $countLeft > 0; $i++) {
            echo $types[$key]['text'] . PHP_EOL;
            // Adjust amount left
            $countLeft--;
            // Flag something put out
            $anyOutput = true;
        }
    }
} while ($anyOutput);
```

Update:
If you have different text values for some of the types, it would need to keep track of this data.

So this code creates an array of each type and a list of the text values for each one, then in the loop it removes the first from the list at each point (using `array_shift`) to output the next one and remove it from the remaining list.

```
// Split into groups by the type
$breakdown = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $breakdown[$item['type']][] = $item['text'];
}
// Sort by the key to create desired order
ksort($breakdown);

$breakSize = 3;

do {
    // If flag doesn't changem then run out of content
    $anyOutput = false;
    foreach ($breakdown as $key => &$textList) {
        // Loop while less than the break size but also with something left
        for ($i = 0; $i < $breakSize && !empty($textList); $i++) {
            echo array_shift($textList) . PHP_EOL;
            // Flag something put out
            $anyOutput = true;
        }
    }
} while ($anyOutput);
```

Comment: This is by far the closest I've seen, but it seems to be not quite the expected result. But props to you for getting close. I've updated my original question to include a better example of what the `$items` array may look like, and one issue I'm having is, it's certainly outputting the same number of items as are in the main array, but the group number is changed... there is no group `1`s. If that makes sense. In my next comment I'll give the output so you can see what I mean.

Comment: `Type of 1 (2) - Type of 1 (2) - Type of 1 (2) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 3 (3) - Type of 3 (3) - Type of 3 (3) - Type of 4 (2) - Type of 4 (2) - Type of 4 (2) - Type of 1 (2) - Type of 1 (2) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 3 (3) - Type of 3 (3) - Type of 3 (3) - Type of 4 (2) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 2 (4) - Type of 2 (4)` Notice how there's not `Group 1` when there should be, and the groups are out of order?

Comment: @quietWind01, I assumed that all type 1's would have the same text.  So your actual data can have the same type but different text?

Comment: @quietWind01 - added new code version for that.

Comment: Yes, essentially. Basically this is for a post system, for a main page feed. I'm gathering all of my posts into an array to display on the feed. But because I'm querying each in order and pushing them to the main array, I don't want it to constantly have all of one type at the top and have the rest buried. It isn't a super complex feed, and I just need it to sort it in some way where it alternates the type of post shown. My actual code is a bit different than this, but I'm intelligent enough to have the concept explained and integrate it how I need it so I more or less just need the concept.

Comment: But also to preface that, not only does it need to alternate the post shown, it needs to do so in ascending order so that each group of 3 of each post type are shown first. So even if they aren't 100% in order of post date (technically I'm going by the post's ID), that isn't a big deal to me.

Comment: @quietWind01 this should be the updated version of the code - have you tried it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255990/discussion-between-quietwind01-and-nigel-ren).

Comment: Uh, if you read our chat, yours did work--it was just a 'me' error. But, once I realized that, you had the correct answer until @mickmack posted his answer which was shorter, sweeter, simpler and IMO, easier to understand (no offense). So I switched the correct answer to his.

Answer (score -1):

First of all

> I can't seem to find an algorithm to match what I'm trying to do. I can't seem to find much, and I'm beginning to wonder if the algorithm I'm looking for doesn't actually exist yet

yes, you are right, it does not exists and should not exists ever, the Algorithm should not be exists to output a specific result. it should be used to perform a specific behavior/function rather than achieve/output a specific result.

however, you can sort an array based on it's key using [`uasort`](https://php.net/uasort) like following:

```
$items = [
    ["type" => 1, "text" => "Type of 1"],
    ["type" => 1, "text" => "Type of 1"],
    ["type" => 1, "text" => "Type of 1"],
    ["type" => 1, "text" => "Type of 1"],
    ["type" => 2, "text" => "Type of 2"],
    ["type" => 2, "text" => "Type of 2"],
    ["type" => 2, "text" => "Type of 2"],
    ["type" => 2, "text" => "Type of 2"],
];

uasort($items, fn ($a, $b) => $a > $b ? 1 : -1); 

print_r($items);
```

Then, you can use something like [`array_column`](https://php.net/array_column) in a combination with implode to extract the item as a value in a one-linear fashion, or you can use the `foreach` loops as you already mentioned.

Comment: Isn't that kind of what I'm trying to do? Use it to perform a specific behavior/function? I'll edit my question in the morning. Essentially I want it to alternate them in groups of 3 (or any number but using 3 as an example) and output them. This would have to be done with some sort of intelligent sorting algorithm because Essentially it'd have to move up and down the array. I'll update my question in the morning to be more specific.

Comment: What do you mean by `alternate them in groups of 3`? what if your dataset has more than 5 types with id 9? it will be considered or discarded?

Comment: There wouldn't be anything past type "9". But I'd also like to let it work the same way if I decided to add more "types" later. In my original question in the comments, I've made what I think is a pretty decent analogy to better explain it. But basically I want it to start at the lowest numerical type (so, 1), grab the first 3 of those that show up in the `$items` array, and then either push those to a new array, or just display them (either works). Then move to the next type (2) and do the same. Once you've gotten one round down to 8, repeat the process.

Comment: Any PHP application modern enough to use arrow functions should not be returning a ternary result inside a callback which expects a three-way comparison. Anyhow, if this was the correct advice, you should have voted to close because sorting arrays is a well-worn topic on Stack Overflow. If you are not going to do anything special with `$a` and `$b`, then don't bother to write a custom callback -- just use `asort()` or `arsort()`.